# how to display past date in dialogflow using @sys.date?

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

User's phrase - *"I want details of 14th Jan."*

@sys.date passses the parameter value as **2020-01-14** to the webhook, but here I want to pass value of parameter as **2019-01-14**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user will have to specify what year they want for example:

**i want details of 14th Jan this year**

returned: **2019-01-14**

**i want details of 14th Jan last year**

returned: **2018-01-14**

You can also use **$date.recent** It will always try to convert the phrase into most recent date.

Check below example:
[image]

**Date**: returned **2020-01-14** 
**Date.recent**: returned **2019-01-14**

Comment: but, here I am passing value to webhook, so how can I use date.recent?

Comment: I don't think there is a direct way to do send that to your webhook but if you dont want to insist on the user to specify the year, as a workaround you could parse the fulfillmentMessages in your webhook in which you will add the $date.recent and always use that instead of of queryResult parameters

Comment: yes yes I found that on JSON request to webhook...!! thanks for help.